# Only bitwise operations for std::byte in C++17?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, byte, std-byte

In [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) it is stated that:

> `std::byte` is a distinct type that implements the concept of byte as specified in the C++ language definition.
>
> Like char and unsigned char, it can be used to access raw memory occupied by other objects ([object representation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object)), but unlike those types, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type. A byte is only a collection of bits, and **only bitwise operators are defined for it**.

But that's not true: since it is an enumeration type, the compare operations (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`) are also possible.

Is this intentional, e.g. to use `std::byte` also as a key for `std::map`, etc.?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's intentional that `std::byte` has comparison operators. The proposal for `std::byte` says this:

> Similarly, `std::byte` can be compared, as comparing and ordering instances is a sensible and useful
> operation. Given its underlying storage type, the comparison operators would give the same results as if
> performed on the underlying type.

- [P0298r3 A byte type definition](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0298r3.pdf)

As you've pointed out, this allows using `std::byte` as keys in containers. It also allows using `std::byte` in algorithms like `std::partition`, `std::sort`, `std::unique`, etc., where equality or less-than comparison is needed.

Note that the [Common definitions](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.types) library section in the C++ standard doesn't say much about `std::byte`. It doesn't say that it's not meant to be comparable.

Keep in mind that cppreference isn't normative, and is editable by anyone<sup>*</sup> without opening an account. There are numerous sections that are incomplete, and errors frequently make their way into the wiki. Most likely, the author forgot that `std::byte` also has comparison operators.

---

<sup>*</sup> In fact, I've just edited the page myself, and it now says:

> A byte is only a collection of bits, and only bitwise and comparison operators are defined for it.

Comment: Good job fixing that! It probably meant "Only bitwise operators, as opposed to arithmetic ones like `+`, are implemented", but as phrased it was not very clear.